# Adding data to Geodjango Polygon object (and have it carry through operations)

Tags: geodjango

I would like to add extra information (such as speed and direction) to the base Polygon class and I'd like to maintain that data when performing operations such as convex_hull (extra data shouldn't need to change) or cascaded_union/unary_union (need some functionality to merge the extra data - simple average is probably good enough).

My first thought was that I would subclass the django.contrib.gis.geos. Polygon class.

I initially tried that but even when I create an instance of my new class, I still seem to get back the base Polygon class. I'm also not clear on how to handle the merging of the extra data.

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Polygon

class ExtendedPolygon( Polygon ):
    '''
    extension of Polygon to add altitude, direction and speed 
    '''
    def __init__( self, point_list ): 
        super( ExtendedPolygon, self).__init__( point_list )
        self._altitude = 0
        self._direction = 0
        self._speed = 0

    def __str__(self):
        return "EXT_POLYGON - alt: %d, dir: %d, speed: %d - %s" %    (self._altitude, self._direction, self._speed, self.wkt )
```

However, when I try this, even though I instantiate an ExtendedPolygon, I get back the base class.  My attributes are there, but printing it doesn't work as expected:

```
>>> from extpoly import *
>>> points = ((-75.1, 34.3), (-74.9, 34.3), (-74.9, 34.4), (-75.1, 34.4), (-75.1, 34.3))
>>> ex = ExtendedPolygon( points )
>>> ex
<Polygon object at 0xff6f1144L>
>>> type(ex)
<class 'django.contrib.gis.geos.polygon.Polygon'>
>>> print ex
POLYGON ((-75.09999999999999 34.3, -74.90000000000001 34.3, -74.90000000000001 34.4, -75.09999999999999 34.4, -75.09999999999999 34.3))
```

This also doesn't handle the case of carrying the extra data through the convex_hull or cascaded_union operation either.

Is sub-classing Polygon the right way to do this, or is there a better way?